Getting error while calling the sharepoint API for List Data - List Items Data
I'm getting this error while calling the API for getting list Data using PostMan
https://hostname.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/web/lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')/items 
for above request below is the response
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2147467259, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Cannot complete this action.\n\nPlease try again."
        }
    }
}


Meanwhile i'm getting data for the same list while calling on ConnectPnPOnline using terminal as i have atached below for reference

meanwhile for refrence i'm also attaching some of the list metadata details below
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://domian.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Lists/@Element",
    "odata.type": "SP.List",
    "odata.id": "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/Web/Lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')",
    "odata.etag": "\"4\"",
    "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')",
    "AllowContentTypes": true,
    "BaseTemplate": 1331,
    "BaseType": 0,
    "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
    "CrawlNonDefaultViews": false,
    "Created": "2022-11-16T11:10:40Z",
    "CurrentChangeToken": {
        "StringValue": "1;3;be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536;638513631004800000;297591295"
    },
    "DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "DefaultItemOpenUseListSetting": false,
    "Description": "",
    "Direction": "none",
    "DisableCommenting": false,
    "DisableGridEditing": false,
    "DocumentTemplateUrl": null,
    "DraftVersionVisibility": 0,
    "EnableAttachments": true,
    "EnableFolderCreation": true,
    "EnableMinorVersions": false,
    "EnableModeration": false,
    "EnableRequestSignOff": true,
    "EnableVersioning": false,
    "EntityTypeName": "Model_x0020_Usage",
    "ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles": false,
    "FileSavePostProcessingEnabled": false,
    "ForceCheckout": false,
    "HasExternalDataSource": false,
    "Hidden": false,
    "Id": "be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536",
    "ImagePath": {
        "DecodedUrl": "/_layouts/15/images/itgen.gif?rev=47"
    },
    "ImageUrl": "/_layouts/15/images/itgen.gif?rev=47",
    "DefaultSensitivityLabelForLibrary": "",
    "SensitivityLabelToEncryptOnDownloadForLibrary": null,
    "IrmEnabled": false,
    "IrmExpire": false,
    "IrmReject": false,
    "IsApplicationList": false,
    "IsCatalog": false,
    "IsPrivate": false,
    "ItemCount": 4,
    "LastItemDeletedDate": "2024-05-15T05:46:28Z",
    "LastItemModifiedDate": "2024-05-15T05:46:28Z",
    "LastItemUserModifiedDate": "2024-05-15T05:46:28Z",
    "ListExperienceOptions": 0,
    "ListItemEntityTypeFullName": "SP.Data.Model_x0020_UsageItem",
    "MajorVersionLimit": 0,
    "MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit": 0,
    "MultipleDataList": false,
    "NoCrawl": false,
    "ParentWebPath": {
        "DecodedUrl": "/sites/random_site"
    },
    "ParentWebUrl": "/sites/random_site",
    "ParserDisabled": false,
    "ServerTemplateCanCreateFolders": true,
    "TemplateFeatureId": "",
    "Title": "Model Usage"
}

I'm expecting to get the list items by calling the microsoft rest api for sharepoint.
But it is returning the error 500.
I got the results when i added the query in a discriptive manner and got the result but this doesn't look good and seems a but messy but the below one gave the result atleast?:
https://hostname.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/web/lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')/items$select=FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject,RoleAssignments,AttachmentFiles,ContentType,GetDlpPolicyTip,FieldValuesAsHtml,FieldValuesAsText,FieldValuesForEdit,File,Folder,LikedByInformation,ParentList,Properties,Versions,FileSystemObjectType,Id,ServerRedirectedEmbedUri,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl,ContentTypeId,Title,ComplianceAssetId,OData__ColorTag,ID,Modified,Created,AuthorId,EditorId,OData__UIVersionString,Attachments,GUID,FileRef,FileDirRef,FileLeafRef,UniqueId,EncodedAbsUrl
the below api is returning 200 as response: https://hostname.sharepoint.com/sites/random_site/_api/web/lists(guid'be7ca91-2715-4b86-8299-7925f99b7536')/items
Do u have any better solution or i have to send the query in this very messy format?

Try this query https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testrukk/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ruklist')/items?$select=Id,Title,GUID and pass header as Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

The above query works for me check this

I generate access token like below via Postman:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret


I created a list in SharePoint:

To List Items Data, modify the query like below:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testrukk/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ruklist')/items?$select=Id,Title,GUID

Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"


When tried in PowerShell I got the same results:
Get-PnPListItem -List "ruklist"


Reference:
Working with lists and list items with REST | Microsoft

I have made some observational changes in my Question can u follow up?

Can you brief your requirement?

the api is working with select query. But post removing it doesn't work? can u know the possible reason.

AFAIK it by default

Hence you can make use of the query posted in my answer
